# Rstudio doesn't start from anaconda

Tags: anaconda, rstudio

I have been using Rstudio through Anaconda for a while and everything was smooth. However, without any prior issue, when I try to run Rstudio a navigation window popups asking for directory to save download file
[image: The window that popups instead of Rstudio]

I just tried to choose a name and hit save but nothing happened. I tried to reset anaconda navigator and using `conda update conda` command to update packages but nothing changed. Does anyone has any idea that what should I do to make Rstudio works again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had this issue arise for both myself and a friend after installing the most recent Windows 10 update (to build 1803) - hope this is the same case as you, as it might mean it's a reproducible issue.

Try uninstalling Anaconda, and retrying with a fresh install of R & RStudio (worked for me, does take a while for Anaconda to uninstall especially if you've got multiple environments or lots of packages), or roll back Windows to an earlier version (worked for my friend).

Comment: Oh that's really bad. Yep I just installed new update of windows 10. Thanks